# How to use reflection in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dependency-injection, angularjs-injector

I have a case where I'm receiving a message from signalr and I'm trying to instantiate a object based on a name that I get in the message.

I had a similar case in angularjs where we solved it using an $injector that has $injector.get("Name") which returns an object that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue provides no DI container that can help with this. Basically there should be a map that links classes or factory functions to string identifiers:

```
const servicesMap = {
  Foo,
  Bar
};

...

if (!Object.keys(servicesMap).includes(name))
  throw ...

const Service = servicesMap[name];
const service = new Service();
```

Considering that services can be imported from a single folder, this can be done with dynamic imports:

```
const Service = require(`.../services/${name}`).default;
const service = new Service();
```

This depends on project setup and automatically disables treeshaking for `services`.

Comment: Ok I got something but now the question is how should I define a "Service" in the first place.

Comment: Foo, etc are just classes that are instantiated. If you don't use classes much then limit this to factory functions, e.g. `createFoo`, where it's a factory that returns service instance, so it would be `const createService = ...; const service = createService()`.

Comment: first of all I want to show what I'm trying to call. `export default class EditLocationSagaResponseHandler {
    constructor(){}
    handle(response) {
        var notification = {
            id: response.requestId,
            title: i18n('translations.location_operation_edit_title'),
            workerStatus: workerStatus.success,
            errors: response.errors
        };
        store.addNotification(notification);
    }
}`

Comment: So I trying to call handle method.

Comment: Your factory can look like `createHandler = () => new EditLocationSagaResponseHandler()` and then you do `handlerFactories[name]().handle(...)`, I guess. You can cache `handlerFactories[name]()` to make it a singleton like it's in Angular DI.